# Username and Password not saving to text file

Tags: python

So I am writing a program that does multiple tasks but I am trying to add a section where a new user can sign up with a login. I created the code that opens up a text file that stores the username and password, checks to see if the username is already in use, and then adds the new username and password that can then be used in a authentication program to verify that the username and password belong to each other and this all works great on its own. The problem I run into is when I add it to my main program it will run through the code and then after saying "Account Created" it jumps back to the main menu for the user to do more things but when I check the file to see if the username and password have been added there is no new username or password. Why is it not storing the information? For context all functions in code are defined within the same python file.

```
def signup():
    clear()
    print("Create an account!")
    userLoginInfo = open("usersInfo.txt", 'r')
    Username = input("Create Username:")
    Password = input("create Password:")
    usernamelist = []
    passwordlist = []
    for i in userLoginInfo:
        usernameEntered, passwordEntered = i.split(", ")
        passwordEntered = passwordEntered.strip()
        usernamelist.append(usernameEntered)
        passwordlist.append(passwordEntered)
    data = dict(zip(usernamelist, passwordlist))

    if Username in usernamelist:
        print("Username Already Exists, Please Try again")
        signup()
    else:
        userLoginInfo = open("usersInfo.txt", "a")
        userLoginInfo.write("\n"+Username+", "+Password)
        print("Account Created")
    main_menu()
```

Comment: You need to close the file after writing to it so the buffer is flushed. Use `with` to make this happen automatically.

Comment: You need to close the file.

Comment: Does closing the file opened in read-mode solve the trouble while you append the new value(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is really great all you're missing is...

```
if Username in usernamelist:
    print("Username Already Exists, Please Try again")
    signup()
else:
    userLoginInfo = open("usersInfo.txt", "a")
    userLoginInfo.write("\n"+Username+", "+Password)
    userLoginInfo.close()
    print("Account Created")
main_menu()
```

You need to close the txt file after writing to it.